# Fitting model with unstructured covariance matrix with gls in R

Tags: r, stata, lme4-nlme

Consider the following dataset:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

data<-sleepstudy
data<-data[data$Days<5,]
data$b<-sample(0:1,nrow(data), rep=T)
```

I am trying to replicate the results of this Stata code in R:

```
use data, clear
xtmixed Reaction Days##b || Subject: , nocon reml residuals(un, t(Days) by(b) )
```

This is basically a model for longitudinal data with unstructured mean and covariance matrix, and heteroscedasticity by a grouping factor b.

Since, due to the nocon option, there is no random effect, I thought the right function to use was gls. Currently I was fitting the following model:

```
fit <- gls(Reaction ~ Days*b , data = data, corr=corSymm(form=~1|Subject),
weights=varIdent(form=~1|Days*b), method="REML", na.action=na.omit)
```

However, looking at the output:

```
Correlation Structure: General
Formula: ~1 | Subject 
Parameter estimate(s):
Correlation: 
  1     2     3     4    
2 0.859                  
3 0.703 0.876            
4 0.732 0.870 0.951      
5 0.625 0.743 0.815 0.931
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Days * b 
 Parameter estimates:
      0*1       1*0       2*1       3*1       4*0       0*0       1*1           2*0       4*1 
1.0000000 1.3521764 0.5289573 1.5353564 1.2546706 1.2076804 0.9908704 1.1038659 1.5339758 
      3*0 
1.0425169
```

this seems to correctly give a different variance for each level of b and time point, but a common correlation for both levels of grouping factor b. I tried with corr=corSymm(form=~1|Subject/b) but this did not make a difference.

Is it possible to allow for grouping level b-specific correlations?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the correlation structures that are available for `gls()`, via its `correlation` argument do not allow to estimate correlation parameters conditional on covariates.

However, for the specific model you want to fit, and because both the mean and variance-covariance structure are different for the two levels of `b`, you could split your dataset into two parts according to the levels of `b` and estimate the model in each part.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Dimitris. That's unfortunate. Yes, for this specific toy example that is true, I could just split the data in two parts, but things are different in the actual data example I have.